# BootStrap Transition to next tab from Carousel with manos.malihu plugin

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, browser, touch, swipe

Please help me in finding a solution that will be very useful for many other people after me.

I have a simple/standard carousel made in Bootstrapie. The problem starts when I want with the swipe right or left go to next or previous tab in the carousel at the browser in Android. 
I know that is the mass of plug-ins that provide such functionality Bootstrapping carousel. I used the simplest way using component "touch" from jQuery Mobile. When I use desktop browser (chrome, ff, opera) and using the mouse to swipe left/right it all works nicely (changing cards). 
However, when I use the android browser I haven't such a possibility. My diagnosed why this happens (unfortunately, this is so independent of plugin enabled swipe and I lost a lot of time trying to find a running plugin - tested hammer.js bootstrap-touch-carousel.js, slick.js, jquery.touchSwipe.js, etc.). The reason is use by me a configurable scrollbar'a from [plugin - manos.malihu](http://manos.malihu.gr/). My diagnosis is to find part of code in the above plugin: jquery.Custom Scrollbar.js whose responsible for swipe (and blocking swipe from e.g. jQuery Mobile). Below I paste code responsible for the swipe in manos.malihu plugin:

```
/*
  TOUCH SWIPE EVENTS
  scrolls content via touch swipe
  Emulates the native touch-swipe scrolling with momentum found in iOS, Android and WP devices
  */
  _contentDraggable=function(){
     var $this=$(this),d=$this.data(pluginPfx),o=d.opt,
        namespace=pluginPfx+"_"+d.idx,
        mCustomScrollBox=$("#mCSB_"+d.idx),
        mCSB_container=$("#mCSB_"+d.idx+"_container"),
        mCSB_dragger=[$("#mCSB_"+d.idx+"_dragger_vertical"),$("#mCSB_"+d.idx+"_dragger_horizontal")],
        draggable,dragY,dragX,touchStartY,touchStartX,touchMoveY=[],touchMoveX=[],startTime,runningTime,endTime,distance,speed,amount,
        durA=0,durB,overwrite=o.axis==="yx" ? "none" : "all",touchIntent=[],touchDrag,docDrag,
        iframe=mCSB_container.find("iframe"),
        events=[
           "touchstart."+namespace+" pointerdown."+namespace+" MSPointerDown."+namespace, //start
           "touchmove."+namespace+" pointermove."+namespace+" MSPointerMove."+namespace, //move
           "touchend."+namespace+" pointerup."+namespace+" MSPointerUp."+namespace //end
        ],
        touchAction=document.body.style.touchAction!==undefined;
     mCSB_container.bind(events[0],function(e){
        _onTouchstart(e);
     }).bind(events[1],function(e){
        _onTouchmove(e);
     });
     mCustomScrollBox.bind(events[0],function(e){
        _onTouchstart2(e);
     }).bind(events[2],function(e){
        _onTouchend(e);
     });
     if(iframe.length){
        iframe.each(function(){
           $(this).load(function(){
              /* bind events on accessible iframes */
              if(_canAccessIFrame(this)){
                 $(this.contentDocument || this.contentWindow.document).bind(events[0],function(e){
                    _onTouchstart(e);
                    _onTouchstart2(e);
                 }).bind(events[1],function(e){
                    _onTouchmove(e);
                 }).bind(events[2],function(e){
                    _onTouchend(e);
                 });
              }
           });
        });
     }
     function _onTouchstart(e){
        if(!_pointerTouch(e) || touchActive || _coordinates(e)[2]){touchable=0; return;}
        touchable=1; touchDrag=0; docDrag=0; draggable=1;
        $this.removeClass("mCS_touch_action");
        var offset=mCSB_container.offset();
        dragY=_coordinates(e)[0]-offset.top;
        dragX=_coordinates(e)[1]-offset.left;
        touchIntent=[_coordinates(e)[0],_coordinates(e)[1]];
     }
     function _onTouchmove(e){
        if(!_pointerTouch(e) || touchActive || _coordinates(e)[2]){return;}
        if(!o.documentTouchScroll){e.preventDefault();}
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        if(docDrag && !touchDrag){return;}
        if(draggable){
           runningTime=_getTime();
           var offset=mCustomScrollBox.offset(),y=_coordinates(e)[0]-offset.top,x=_coordinates(e)[1]-offset.left,
              easing="mcsLinearOut";
           touchMoveY.push(y);
           touchMoveX.push(x);
           touchIntent[2]=Math.abs(_coordinates(e)[0]-touchIntent[0]); touchIntent[3]=Math.abs(_coordinates(e)[1]-touchIntent[1]);
           if(d.overflowed[0]){
              var limit=mCSB_dragger[0].parent().height()-mCSB_dragger[0].height(),
                 prevent=((dragY-y)>0 && (y-dragY)>-(limit*d.scrollRatio.y) && (touchIntent[3]*2<touchIntent[2] || o.axis==="yx"));
           }
           if(d.overflowed[1]){
              var limitX=mCSB_dragger[1].parent().width()-mCSB_dragger[1].width(),
                 preventX=((dragX-x)>0 && (x-dragX)>-(limitX*d.scrollRatio.x) && (touchIntent[2]*2<touchIntent[3] || o.axis==="yx"));
           }
           if(prevent || preventX){ /* prevent native document scrolling */
              if(!touchAction){e.preventDefault();}
              touchDrag=1;
           }else{
              docDrag=1;
              $this.addClass("mCS_touch_action");
           }
           if(touchAction){e.preventDefault();}
           amount=o.axis==="yx" ? [(dragY-y),(dragX-x)] : o.axis==="x" ? [null,(dragX-x)] : [(dragY-y),null];
           mCSB_container[0].idleTimer=250;
           if(d.overflowed[0]){_drag(amount[0],durA,easing,"y","all",true);}
           if(d.overflowed[1]){_drag(amount[1],durA,easing,"x",overwrite,true);}
        }
     }
     function _onTouchstart2(e){
        if(!_pointerTouch(e) || touchActive || _coordinates(e)[2]){touchable=0; return;}
        touchable=1;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        _stop($this);
        startTime=_getTime();
        var offset=mCustomScrollBox.offset();
        touchStartY=_coordinates(e)[0]-offset.top;
        touchStartX=_coordinates(e)[1]-offset.left;
        touchMoveY=[]; touchMoveX=[];
     }
     function _onTouchend(e){
        if(!_pointerTouch(e) || touchActive || _coordinates(e)[2]){return;}
        draggable=0;
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        touchDrag=0; docDrag=0;
        endTime=_getTime();
        var offset=mCustomScrollBox.offset(),y=_coordinates(e)[0]-offset.top,x=_coordinates(e)[1]-offset.left;
        if((endTime-runningTime)>30){return;}
        speed=1000/(endTime-startTime);
        var easing="mcsEaseOut",slow=speed<2.5,
           diff=slow ? [touchMoveY[touchMoveY.length-2],touchMoveX[touchMoveX.length-2]] : [0,0];
        distance=slow ? [(y-diff[0]),(x-diff[1])] : [y-touchStartY,x-touchStartX];
        var absDistance=[Math.abs(distance[0]),Math.abs(distance[1])];
        speed=slow ? [Math.abs(distance[0]/4),Math.abs(distance[1]/4)] : [speed,speed];
        var a=[
           Math.abs(mCSB_container[0].offsetTop)-(distance[0]*_m((absDistance[0]/speed[0]),speed[0])),
           Math.abs(mCSB_container[0].offsetLeft)-(distance[1]*_m((absDistance[1]/speed[1]),speed[1]))
        ];
        amount=o.axis==="yx" ? [a[0],a[1]] : o.axis==="x" ? [null,a[1]] : [a[0],null];
        durB=[(absDistance[0]*4)+o.scrollInertia,(absDistance[1]*4)+o.scrollInertia];
        var md=parseInt(o.contentTouchScroll) || 0; /* absolute minimum distance required */
        amount[0]=absDistance[0]>md ? amount[0] : 0;
        amount[1]=absDistance[1]>md ? amount[1] : 0;
        if(d.overflowed[0]){_drag(amount[0],durB[0],easing,"y",overwrite,false);}
        if(d.overflowed[1]){_drag(amount[1],durB[1],easing,"x",overwrite,false);}
     }
     function _m(ds,s){
        var r=[s*1.5,s*2,s/1.5,s/2];
        if(ds>90){
           return s>4 ? r[0] : r[3];
        }else if(ds>60){
           return s>3 ? r[3] : r[2];
        }else if(ds>30){
           return s>8 ? r[1] : s>6 ? r[0] : s>4 ? s : r[2];
        }else{
           return s>8 ? s : r[3];
        }
     }
     function _drag(amount,dur,easing,dir,overwrite,drag){
        if(!amount){return;}
        _scrollTo($this,amount.toString(),{dur:dur,scrollEasing:easing,dir:dir,overwrite:overwrite,drag:drag});
     }
  },
```

I see that in desktop browser is used to swipe from jQuery mobile. Changing cards from carousel works with swipe by mouse (press left mouse button and drag to left or right). 
Code with swipe using jQuery mobile:

```
$('.carousel').swiperight(function() {
   $(this).carousel('prev');
});
$('.carousel').swipeleft(function() {
   $(this).carousel('next');
});
```

After many attempts I cann't make changes in "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js" such to get the same functionality in android browser with touch of a finger. My a function call from "jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js":

```
jQuery('.carousel-item').mCustomScrollbar({ axis:"y", theme: "rounded-dots", scrollButtons: { enable: true }, scrollInertia: 100});
```

For you it will be easier than for me to add/change code snippet in jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js to get similar functionality for both browsers (desktop, android).

P.S.
I warn you, when I use:

```
contentTouchScroll: false
```

In fact, I have similar functionality on both browsers, but this not the way because I block possibility to scroll up/down with touch(swipe) your finger up/down.

Issue reported on github [creator plugin](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/issues/423)

[but I guess that support from creators rather isn't possible at this moment]

I would be very grateful for your help. I lost too much time trying to solve the problem yourself

Regards Zic

Answer (score 0):

This should only remove `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` from above part of plugin (_OnTouch/Start/Move/End)